# how to interact with "Reminder me" in CallKit like whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp, reminders, callkit

My App is compatible with CallKit after iOS 10.0. However, I meet with a problem:
  When there is an incoming call, I just click the "reminder me" button,
then, I open the system app "Reminders", there will be one record of my app call, But how can I set my app icon here and make the icon clickable to call the other, just like “whatsapp” shows~

Comment: Did you find your answer? Did you implemented outgoing calls with CallKit? My guess is that apple will only show icons of app that supports outgoing calls with CallKit.

Comment: @YYamil yes, my app supports outgoing calls with CallKit, but still don't know how to show my icons on "Reminder"

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and solved it by letting iOS now my app can make calls. I did this adding the 'NSUserActivityTypes' array to the info plist file with with these entries: 'INStartAudioCallIntent' and  'INStartVideoCallIntent'.

This is how it looks like: [image]

With this, iOS started showing my app icon in the Reminders app. After that you can implement in your app delegate the `-application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` (or in Swift, `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)`) method to handle the received action and start a call.

Comment: LGTM,Thanks!!  But why all the records are Audio even if I make a Video Call ?

Comment: @foolishBoy, I have no idea. Maybe it's an iOS limitation

Comment: so did you have the same problem?@YYamil

Comment: Yes, I'm having the same issue